# Mongoose - find all fields potential correspondance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

I want to find a way to any correspondance about this both field `title` & `description` from my `Jobs` db, to compare other contains on my list `potentialJobs`

**My** `Jobs` **database fields:**

[image]

I thinking my probleme provide from my variable : `let correspondance = Jobs.find({title: req.body.title , description: req.body.description})`

I inquired everywhere, and it seems `req.body.` be the default value to find any match in all fields

but when i try to run it i got that :

```
ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Timeout.apiToDB [as _onTimeout] (/Users/mac/Desktop/server/config/job.js:49:53)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My code `Job.js` :

```
function apiToDB() {

let correspondance = Jobs.find({title: req.body.title , description: req.body.description})

const potentialJobs = [{ title: 'Electrotechnicien H/F' }, description: 'blabla'
  {
  title: 'Assistant Medical H/F',
  description: '12345....',
  },
  { title: 'Designer H/F', 
  description: 'ABCDE....' }];


      for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(5, potentialJobs.length); i++) {
        if (potentialJobs[i].title && potentialJobs[i].description === correspondance) {
          console.log('This job : ' + potentialJobs[i].title + ' is already exist on DB');
          continue;
        }
        else{
              var title = potentialJobs[i].title;
              var desc = potentialJobs[i].description;
              var url = potentialJobs[i].redirect_url;
              var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("fr")

              console.log( "Job value insert :  " + title + " " + url);
    
              assignDataValue(title, desc, url, date)
            
              continue
            
        }
      }
}
```

If anyone can help me, Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function apiToDB(req, res){
 // your code
}
```

In older express version, you will need to install body-parser : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
and import it like this :

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
```

Comment: Hi, it doesen't work properly, this time is `body` :  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at Timeout.apiToDB [as _onTimeout] (/Users/mac/Desktop/server/config/job.js:49:57)`

Comment: you will need to install body-parser and import it in your file : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Yep `bodyparser` is already present on my code

Comment: did you import it correctly in your **Job.js** file ?

Comment: Yeah and many of them i already imported like `mongoose` `express` `bodyparser` `cors` `exphbs` `morgan`  etc...